# Remove duplicate words in a column with many comma separated words - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Im working with a Dataframe with two columns. Column A contains rows with one category and column B contains many rows with many words, that are comma-separated.

Column B is being updated often and i want to make sure that in column B there is no duplicate words in each row.

I tried `.join(set(text.split(',')))` but get the error

`TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer'.`

And now im stuck...

Comment: please read [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: try this `','.join(set(text.split(',')))`